# Excel Power Query remove merged columns from Excel source before loading

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have an Excel file, first 7 rows are merged. Others are unmerged.
I need to load unmerged rows from Power Query but Excel brings first merged colums and I cannot change/remove.

[image]

First 7 rows B and C Columns are merged. Powerquery loads these rows only which I do not need.

When I manually unmerge these columns Power Query loads correct table. I don't want this manual operation each time.

I need rows starting from 9.

Regards,

I've tried every solution from this site and ChatGPT but didn't solve my problem

-- Edit:
I've realized that problem is auto generated Excel source file.
When I open and save source Excel file withot changing anything, power query loads all rows and I can skip top rows.
Now I try to figure out to automatically fix auto generated source Excel file.

Thanks for all replies.

Comment: Please try this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77016690/6165594)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I do not have problem with CSV files. Source is Excel file.

Answer (score 2):

In powerquery, read in the data, then do

home ... remove rows ... remove top rows ... 8

then

home ... use first row as headers

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply but that is not my question. First 7 rows in original Excel source are merged and loaded only this part. When I remove top 7 rows it remains empty. Power query doesn't load rows after merged rows.

Comment: Please edit your question and paste in your code from home ... advanced editor.  Also provide a sample copy of your data input if that image is not it

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

1. **Manual**: select your table range and through right click select "Get Data from Table/Range..."
   [image]
2. **Auto** (if you don't want to select table range manually): described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77016690/6165594) (I added excel load example together with csv)